# SELECT and UPDATE MySQL query

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to select a field from MySQL table and remove a substring from that field, and update that field.

For example: VAR1010 I want to replace and update VAR with SHS and the remaining part is the same. The result I am expecting is SHS1010

Here is the code:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(R.regnumber,4,4) as RegNo from registration R WHERE R.teacheremail='param';

UPDATE registration  SET regnumber = 'SHSRegNo' where teacheremail='param';
```

But it's updating as `RegNo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in one `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE registration  
SET regnumber = concat('SHS', substr(regnumber, 4, 4))
where teacheremail='param';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3aa6c/1)

Answer (score 2):

Just do that:

```
UPDATE registration  SET regnumber = concat('SHS', substr(regnumber, 4, 4))
WHERE teacheremail='param';
```

Answer (score 1):

use [`replace`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

```
UPDATE registration  SET regnumber =  replace(regnumber,'VAR','SHS')
where teacheremail='param';
```

Comment: your link is off-topic, the question is not about Microsoft SQL server. And your query uses a subquery, this is useless here.